# Upgrade from rails 4.2.4 to 4.2.6 Full error reports in browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my development.rb I have:

```
# Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
```

And when I use rails 4.2.4
If I have some erro in my code rails shows me full error reports in browser just fine.

But when I only change rails version in Gemfile from 4.2.4 to 4.2.5 or 4.2.6

Rails begins show me error like in production mode, just message in browser:

> 500 Internal Server Error

Without any debug info.

Help me please make rails shows me normal error pages in development mode.

My [Gemfile](http://paste.ubuntu.com/15966355/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problems with your configuration or your Gemfile.
It's a little risky but you could try `bundle update` and check if the problem persists. If you use `rvm` create a new `gemset` for this purpose so you can rollback to the previous gemset if something goes wrong.

Also you could try installing `better_errors` gem under **development** group:

```
group :development do
  gem "better_errors"
end
```

`bundle install` and then try again and see if you can see your nicer stack trace on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that problem is with web-console

I had web-console version 2.2.1, after upgrade the new version is 2.3.0
So, I just froze web-console to version 2.2.1

And now everything's work fine